# Can a throw or delete expression ever be dependent?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, dependent-type, compiler-bug

Both gcc 5.0 and clang 3.6 require the `typename` keyword in the following example:

```
template<typename T>
struct B
{
    typedef int Type;
};

template<int n>
struct A
{
    typedef typename B<decltype(throw (int*)n)>::Type Throw;
    typedef typename B<decltype(delete (int*)n)>::Type Delete;
};
```

This is covered by the following wording in the C++11 standard:

> [except]/2
>
> A throw-expression is of type void.
>
> [expr.delete]/1
>
> The operand shall have a pointer to object type, or a class type having a single non-explicit conversion
>   function to a pointer to object type. The result has type void.

So I'm assuming `decltype` produces `void` in both cases.

> [expr.const]/2
>
> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it involves one of the following as a potentially
>   evaluated subexpression
>
> - a new-expression
> - a throw-expression

This suggests that an expression involving either `throw` or `delete` cannot be a constant expression.

> [temp.dep.type]/8
>
> A type is dependent if it is
>
> - a simple-template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template
>     arguments is a dependent type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent
> - denoted by `decltype(expression)`, where expression is type-dependent

So `B<decltype(..)>` is dependent only if the expression is type-dependent.

> [temp.dep.expr]/4
>
> Expressions of the following forms are never type-dependent (because the type of the expression cannot be
>   dependent):
>
> ```
> delete cast-expression
> throw assignment-expression
> ```

This suggests that neither expression can be type-dependent.

Are gcc and clang both wrong?

Comment: I don't think your reasoning about [temp.dep.constexpr]/p1 is correct. A `reinterpret_cast` cannot appear in a constant expression either, but [temp.dep.constexpr]/p3 explicitly specifies that an expression involving a `reinterpret_cast` can be possibly value-dependent.

Comment: `decltype(..)` is not an expression. So you also need [temp.dep.type]/9.8 That paragraph only requires the expression in `decltype(expression)` not to be *type-dependent*, which is well-specified for `throw` and `new`.

Comment: @dyp Yes! That seems conclusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go back to when `typename` is required. §14.6 [temp.res]/p3, all quotes are from N4140:

> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a
>   member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1) and its
>   *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename`, forming a *typename-specifier*.

The *qualified-id* in this case is `B<decltype(throw (int*)n)>::Type` (and the `delete` version, for which the analysis is exactly the same). So `typename` is required if the *nested-name-specifier*, or `B<decltype(throw (int*)n)>::`, refers to a dependent type.

§14.6.2.1 [temp.dep.type]/p8 says, with six unrelated bullets omitted, that

> A type is dependent if it is
>
> [...]
>
> (8.7) — a *simple-template-id* in which either the template name is a
>   template parameter or any of the template arguments is a dependent
>   type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent, or
>
> (8.8) — denoted by `decltype(`*expression*`)`, where *expression* is type-dependent (14.6.2.2).

`B<decltype(throw (int*)n)>` is a *simple-template-id*. The template name, `B`, is not a template parameter. The only template argument, `decltype(throw (int*)n)`, is not an expression, so `B<decltype(throw (int*)n)>` is dependent only if `decltype(throw (int*)n)` is a dependent type. `decltype(throw (int*)n)`, in turn, per bullet 8.8, is only dependent if `throw (int*)n` is type-dependent. But we know that, per §14.6.2.2 [temp.dep.expr]/p4:

> Expressions of the following forms are never type-dependent (because
>   the type of the expression cannot be dependent):
>
> [...]
>
> `::`<sub>*opt*</sub> `delete` *cast-expression*
>
> [...]
>
> `throw` *assignment-expression<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> [...]

Therefore, `throw (int*)n` is not type-dependent, and so `decltype(throw (int*)n)` is not a dependent type, and so `B<decltype(throw (int*)n)>` is not a dependent type, and so `typename` is not required for `B<decltype(throw (int*)n)>::Type`, and so yes, this is a compiler bug.

Comment: Today I finally realized what my mistake is, and found it to be mentioned right in your answer. `decltype(…)` isn't an expression. I never question this and was irritated by `[temp.dep.constexpr]/1`. :)